# Firefox "touch simulation" mode issues three click events for a double tap

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firefox, events

Given a React component:

```
const MyButton = () => {
  const handleClick = (e) => { e.persist(); console.log('handleClick invoked', e) }

  return <button onClick={handleClick}>hello world</button>
}
```

In Firefox dev tools with "touch simulation" on; or on Firefox mobile, when the element is tapped two times in quick succession, the handler is invoked three times.  I cannot see a difference in the event value: all three seem to be "click" events.  (Except the first one has "detail=1", and the second and third have "detail=2" - but I cannot find the explanation of this value in either React's or MDN docs.)

Adding `preventDefault` or `stopPropagation` makes no difference.

The component is not rerendered as a result of the call; wrapping in `useCallback` makes no difference.

Why does it happen?  How do I detect and suppress the superfluous event?

Comment: The best information I could find on this is that there is a 300ms delay between the 'click' event happening and the code registering it. This is due to mobile devices having custom handling for various tap gestures (usually double tap causes a zoom in). I'm still not sure why this causes the event to run three times instead of two. I am running into the same issue, did you ever find a solution?

Comment: I had the same issue here. I am glad to know it's only for firefox mobile view.